# Problem in opening tmux with .tmux.conf configuration

Tags: linux, vim, tmux

I added a `.tmux.conf` configuration file to my home directory while learning about tmux and it started to show something like

```
/home/ghost/.tmux.conf:5: unknown command:
```

My `.tmux.conf` file:

```
# Send Prefix
set-option -g prefix C-a
unbind-key C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix

# Use Alt-arrow keys to switch panes
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D

# Shift arrow to switch windows
bind -n S-Left previous-window
bind -n S-Right next-window

# Mouse mode
setw -g mouse on

# Set easier window split keys
bind-key v split-window -h
bind-key h split-window -v

# Easy config reload
bind-key r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "~/.tmux.conf reloaded."
```

Based on some of the solutions available on the internet I used `cat -A .tmux.conf` and it shows:

```
# Send Prefix^M$
set-option -g prefix C-a^M$
unbind-key C-a^M$
bind-key C-a send-prefix^M$
^M$
# Use Alt-arrow keys to switch panes^M$
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L^M$
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R^M$
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U^M$
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D^M$
^M$
# Shift arrow to switch windows^M$
bind -n S-Left previous-window^M$
bind -n S-Right next-window^M$
^M$
# Mouse mode^M$
setw -g mouse on^M$
^M$
# Set easier window split keys^M$
bind-key v split-window -h^M$
bind-key h split-window -v^M$
^M$
# Easy config reload^M$
bind-key r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "~/.tmux.conf reloaded."^M$
```

In Windows subsystem for linux it also shows something related to `^M` character:

[image: Screenshot from wsl]

I am attaching my `.vimrc` file images:

[image: my .vimrc file]

It's probably due to the `^M` character as I am a beginner in linux, vim and tmux so please guide me.

Please let me know if any other file is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows host and the Linux in WSL are two separate and largely incompatible systems that should interact as little as possible. Whatever is on the Linux side should strictly be handled in Linux with Linux tools and whatever is on the Windows side should strictly be handled in Windows with Windows tools.

In this case, you edited files from the Linux side in a Windows text editor, which had the effect of writing the files with Windows line-ending, `CR`+`LF` (displayed by `cat -A` as `^M$`), while Linux tools generally expect a different line-ending: `LF` (displayed by `cat -A` as `$`).

You can fix those line-endings *in Linux* with this command:

```
$ dos2unix /home/ghost/.tmux.conf
$ dos2unix /home/ghost/.vimrc
```

and you can prevent further errors by adopting a better hygiene: *Windows tools for Windows stuff, Linux tools for Linux stuff*.

Think of WSL as a second laptop, or a remote server, or something along those lines, not as some fancy Windows utility.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great explanation it really worked and I understood the difference between the two as well.

Comment: Thanks!. I was syncing my tmux config with dotbot and had saved some config on windows. Changing the line breaks on mac worked great